# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't  understand why it doesn't work. The addEventListener is not activated

Everything works but when i click on the buttons, the website send me (before starting)

the code is not from me but my mates leaves me 3 days ago and i have to give a webapp in 2 days :).

Any help is welcome.

```
script.js:112 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
    at script.js:112:9
```

then when i click on a button

```
script.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')
    at affectation_valeur (script.js:54:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.init (script.js:65:1)
```

```
<!-- the questions -->
let questions = [
    {
        question: 'Quelle est la capitale de la France?',

        answers:[
            { text : 'bxl', correct:'false', index:1 },
            { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
            { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
      e      { text : 'paris', correct:'correct', index:4 }
        ]
    },

    {
        question: 'Quell est la capitale de la France?',

        answers:[
            { text : 'bxl', correct:'false', index:1 },
            { text : 'juin', correct:'false', index:2 },
            { text : 'ab', correct:'false', index:3 },
            { text : 'paris', correct:'correct', index:4 }
        ]
    }

]



let controls = document.querySelector('.controls');
let start = document.querySelector('#start-btn');
let next = document.querySelector('#next-btn');

let answerButtons = document.querySelector('#answer-buttons');
let btns = document.querySelector('.btn');

let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let questionContainer = document.querySelector('#question-container');
let question = document.querySelector('#question');

let i=0;
let k;
let kl;

let bodyStyle = document.body.style;
container.style.backgroundColor = '#123';

function color_int() {
    bodyStyle.backgroundColor = '#555';
    btns[0].style.backgroundColor='#f00';
    btns[1].style.backgroundColor='#ff0';
    btns[2].style.backgroundColor='#0f0';
    btns[3].style.backgroundColor='#00f';
}

function affectation_valeur(){
btns[0].innerHTML = questions[i].answers[0].text;
btns[1].innerHTML = questions[i].answers[1].text;
btns[2].innerHTML = questions[i].answers[2].text;
btns[3].innerHTML = questions[i].answers[3].text;
}

let init = function() {
questionContainer.style.display = 'block';
start.style.display = 'none';

question.innerHTML = questions[0].question;
affectation_valeur();
color_int();

}



let Reponse = function(e) {
    for (let l = 0; l<=3;l++) { if (questions[i].answers[l].correct == 'true') {x=l;}}
    for (k=0; k<=3; k++){
        if (questions[i].answers[k].correct == 'true'&& questions[i].answers[k].text == e.target.textContent){
            bodyStyle.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
            btns[k].textContent = 'Good';
        }
        
        if (questions[i].answers[k].correct == 'false'&& questions[i].answers[k].text == e.target.textContent){
            bodyStyle.backgroundColor = 'red';
            btns[k].textContent = 'bad';
        }
        if (k!=x){
            btns[k].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            btns[k].textContent = 'bad';
        }else{
            btns[k].style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
            btns[k].textContent = 'good';
        }
    
    }   
    kl = e.target.textContent 
}



let suivant = function(){
    i++;
    if (!kl) {alert('Choissisez une réponse avant de continuer');}
    question.innerHTML = questions[i].question;

    affectation_valeur();
    color_int();
    if(i>4){i=4}
    kl = null;
}

start.addEventListener('click', init, false);
next.addEventListener('click', suivant, false);

btns[0].addEventListener('click', Reponse, false);
btns[1].addEventListener('click', Reponse, false);
btns[2].addEventListener('click', Reponse, false);
btns[3].addEventListener('click', Reponse, false);
```

Comment: `btns` should be initialized with a call to `querySelectorAll()`, not `querySelector()`.

Comment: If you debug your code, you'll see that `btns` is not an array, as inferred by Pointy's comment above.

Comment: Please create a [mre], that way it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mates used `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()` to store the references:

```
let btns = document.querySelector('.btn');
```

Which makes the variable `btns` store the reference to the **first** element it finds that matches the query `.btn`. But when the eventlistners are added, your code is expecting an array, looking for the first element of `btns`, which doesn't exist and thus is undefined:

```
btns[0].addEventListener('click', Reponse, false);
```

To make sure the `btns` stores **all** the elements with class `btn` in an array, use:

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
```

Depending of how the rest of your code looks, you might need to do the same for:

```
let answerButtons = document.querySelector('#answer-buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btns.forEach((btn) => {
   // your logic goes here
   console.log(btn)
})
```